# How To: Flexible Layout with fixed height on a Flash-like site?

Tags: css, html

my question: How could I create a page like
[this one](http://yannis-k.de/jaga) with a flexible with? Is it possible or can't I do it because of the fixed height? I would really like to improve the site's usability. At the moment we get troubled with 800X600 browsers for example.

Of course the site is not yet finished but only a vague idea. Nevertheless I would be happy to hear your comments.

Thanks a lot,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

So, you are looking for the content to stay centered in the browser window? You could do something like this with css and then add the div to your body:

body{height:100%;background-color:#eee}
div{position:absolute;top:25%;bottom:25%;left:25%;right:25%;border:1px solid; width:800px; height:600px;}